# Printing the values from the corresponding array

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Suppose:

```
1    A

2    B

3    C
```

I need to print the value corresponding to `1-> A`. I have put each in an array:
`d1[1,2,3]` and `s1[A,B,C]`. Now I need to print the value in the form shown in the above:

```
d1[0]   s1[0]

1         A
```

How can I do this using UnityScript? In the program, I did id printing in this format:

```
1  A

1  B

1  C

2  A

2  B

2  C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have probably done, and I'm guessing without seeing the code is something along that you have a for loop within a for loop which means you're processing the first item in the first array and then all items in the second:

```
for (var i = 0; i < d1.Length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < s1.length; j++ {
        Debug.log(d1[i] + " " + s1[j]) 
    }
}
```

Your options depend on the array sizes and how you want to handle them. For example if you know they're the same size consistently then

```
for(var i = 0; i < d1.Length; i++) {
   Debug.log(d1[i] + " " + s1[i]) 
}
```

should work. I would wonder if what you're trying to achieve could be done with a different data structure such as a dictionary, etc.

Comment: Suppose I have an array s1 in need to insert number from 1 to 2 float values.How can I do this?Please help me

Comment: Your question is vague. Insert float values where? Do you mean you want to create an array of floats?

Comment: ya I have displayed a float values from 0 to 2                                                                   ` for( i=0;i<=n;i+=0.01f)
  {

    Debug.Log(i);

  }`                                                                     Now I need to insert the numbers into an array

Comment: Welcome, first-time-answerer. Good on you for attempting to answer this. In my opinion, answering questions that are this mangled is counter-productive, because there's nothing useful for any future visitors. Maybe edit it into better shape (there's a badge for that now).  Another reason to close rather than answer it: it's not gamedev-related whatsoever. Maybe it could get migrated to SO...at least it would get to hang out with all the other terrible javascript questions that get rewarded with 10 answers. Again, good job _not_ throwing a js-fiddle solution at such a bad post.

Comment: +1 also for the suggestion that it's an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341).